# Perl Click Button with WWW::Mechanize

Tags: javascript, html, perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize

I'm new to web scraping with Perl, and I'm trying to submit the page by filling in username and password fields, and clicking submit. I inspected the HTML code of the button in question, and it looks like:

```
<input type="submit" class="button formSubmission" value="Sign In">
```

I read that `WWW::Mechanize` can't handle JavaScript, but I'm not sure if the code I'm looking at is JavaScript, or my implementation is just wrong. I tried `$mech->click_button("Sign In");` halfheartedly, but received the error that no such field existed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button doesn't have `name` attribute that's why I'm sure *there is no need to click it*. What you need is **just submit your fields to the form**:

```
$mech->submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        your_username_field => $user,
        your_password_field => $password,
        .....
    },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-click_button) for the `click_button` method. It lists several possible ways to look up the button you want to click. Your button doesn't have a name but it does have a value, so

```
$mech->click_button( value => "Sign In" );
```

should do it.

Comment: It returns the error `Can't call method "header" on an undefined value at /Library/Perl/5.12/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 2471`.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` attribute of an `<input>` is no identifier. In the case of a `submit` button, this is just the text on the button.

If you simply want to submit a form, you may just want `submit_form`.

If you want to click a button, but this button does not have a identifying `name`, then you may want to use the features `click_button` offers. You could specify

```
$mech->click_button(value => "Sign In");
```